# Get time from entire date

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have to get time from entire date

e.g.  time=`11:00:00` from date `2012-09-01 11:00:00.0`

I tried following snippet but getting error `Error : Unparseable date: "2012-9-1.13.30. 0. 0"`

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date date = inputFormat.parse(iResultSet1.getString(i));
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
String outputString = outputFormat.format(date);
```

Edit: Now I am getting only date instead I want only time

```
                             if (iResultSet1.getDate(i) != null) {
                            Date date = iResultSet1.getDate(i);

                            System.out.println("date-->" + date);
                            // Format date into output format
                            DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                    "HH:mm:ss");
                            String outputString = outputFormat.format(date);

                            // System.out.println("date1-->"+date1);
```

Comment: Your data does not look like "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" with all those dots in there

Comment: why is your date format "2012-9-1.13.30. 0. 0" when you are expecting it to be "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"?

Comment: Where do you get this error? seems 2nd line? Did you checked what is returned by iResultSet1.getString(i) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wil suggest, in this case rather doing parsing and manipulation in java change your SQL to format and return only date as

**Example**

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably retrieving your date from the database `(iResultSet1.getString(i))` and the problem is that you're getting wrong format, i.e. 2012-9-1.13.30. 0. 0. Either change the date format in the database or use:

```
Date date = iResultSet1.getDate(i);
```

instead of

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date date = inputFormat.parse(iResultSet1.getString(i));
```

Comment: I tried getDate() and now I am nnot getting any error but instead of time ,I am getting date i.e. 2012-09-01

Comment: Please post what kind of field is in database. If it's timestamp, then use `Timestamp tst = iResultSet1.getTimestamp(i);`